# Epigraph of a function f: D $\rightarrow$ R is convex iff epif(f) is a subset of D*R which is a convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

As in the topic, how to show that $epi(f)$ is convex iff $epi(f)$ belongs to D*R which is a convex set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B)$ be in epi$(f) \subset D \times \mathbb R$. By definition of the epigraph, $f(x_A) \leq y_A$ and $f(x_B) \leq y_B$. Now let $t \in [0,1]$, and consider $ tA + (1-t)B = (x_{tA + (1-t)B},y_{tA + (1-t)B})= (t x_A + (1-t) x_B, ty_A + (1-t) y_B)$ by linearity of the projection.
First assume that $f$ is convex. Then
$$ f(t x_A + (1-t) x_B)  \leq t f(x_A) + (1-t) f (x_B) \leq ty_A + (1-t) y_B,   $$
which proves the implication $f$ convex $\Longrightarrow $ epi$(f)$ convex. Now assume that epi$(f)$ is convex and consider the points $A' = (x_A,f(x_A))$ and $B'=(x_B,f(x_B))$. By convexity of epi$(f)$, $ tA' + (1-t) B' \in$ epi$(f)$, which implies that 
$$ t f(x_A) + (1-t) f(x_B) \geq f(t x_A + (1-t) x_B) $$
so $f$ is convex.